# Missing values error in Oracle dynamic SQL. For the below query its throwing missing values keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic

```
create or replace procedure temp_test_tb(A varchar2 ) is
lsql varchar(4000);
new_table_name varchar2(100);
fz_date timestamp(50);
begin
select timestamp(max(completion_dt)) into freeze_date from  status where  run_status=1;

new_table_name := 'common_' ||A|| '_' ||to_char(add_months(fz_date, -1), 'MON');

lsql:='insert into os_temp_tab_2'||
'select * from'||new_table_name||' WHERE ROWNUM<10';
execute immediate lsql;
commit;
end;
```

This query is throwing an error

> Missing values keyword

in Oracle. My inserting table has same columns as the insertion table.

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message?

Comment: ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword

Comment: Please add every relevant information to the question, not to the comment section

Comment: Use `dbms_output.put_line(lsql);` before you execute it to see and visually verify the generated statement. (And `set serveroutput on` or equivalent, of course.) Aside from the missing whitespace, are you sure `new_table_name` is what you expect?

Comment: Also are you getting a complication error or a run-time error? WHat you've shown has other issues - `timestamp(50)` isn't valid; you declare `fz_date` but then select into `freeze_date`; `timestamp()` isn't a function... So I think what you've posted isn't your real code (as the error you get looks like it is run-time).

Comment: Thank you so much Alex with dbms_output.put_line(lsql); i understood where the error is and its working fine.I want to give input to procedure accurate with seconds as date datatype not allowing i used timestamp(9) data type however still i need to check it whether it is working or not. As i can't submit exact code in the site i changed code,variables slightly i missed to change freeze_date to fz_date .Once again thanks for the help.

Comment: @Learner - the date datatype does give you the time too, down to seconds. (And timestamp allows fractional seconds, and variations can support time zones).

Answer (score 2):

missing space after from

```
' select * from '||new_table_name|| ' WHERE ROWNUM<10 ';
```

Comment: ' select * from '||new_table_name|| '  WHERE ROWNUM<10 ';  for this its thrwoing sql command not properly ended error.